# Simulator screen reloads on state update

Tags: xcode, react-native

Hi I'm experiencing this simulator screen reload problem whenever my value state changes.
I know that it will re-render but I cannot continue typing because the xcode screen reloads whenever I type something in the field.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {TextInput} from 'react-native';

const SampleApp = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  return(
    <TextInput
      onChangeText={(text) => setValue(text)}
      value={value}
    />
  );
};

export default SampleApp;
```

Comment: Is the screen reloading whenever you're typing in the code or on the screen?

Comment: @PrãtéékThápá: sorry i edited the description, my xcode screen reloads whenever i type on the inputfield

Comment: Are you trying to say "Your simulator reloads" whenever you type something in the code?

Comment: @PrãtéékThápá yes exactly, sorry my english not too good

Comment: This is because of `fast refresh`.
1. Open Developer Menu.
2. Press `Disable Fast Refresh`

Comment: @PrãtéékThápá hello, I have tried disabling Fast Refresh but it's still the same.